# Printing message indefinitely while waiting for input on separate threads/processes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using a raspberry pi (Running latest Jessie Raspbian build) to create an embedded system for a project. The devices that are connected have libraries in Python that I'm trying to connect. However, this is my first time really even touching python (I usually work in Java or C/C++) so excuse my lack of knowledge in advance.

So far I can make my keypad and lcd screen interact, but not simultaneously. I want to make the LCD screen cycle through a list of options, while also listening for keypad input.

```
def WelcomeMessage():
    while 1:
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message(...) #top line of lcd
        lcd.message(...) #bottom line of lcd
        time.sleep(3)
        #more messages
```

And listening for keypad input is simple

```
#in the main function
digit = None
while digit == None:
    digit = kp.getKey()
```

I tried using multiprocess, and using  `Start()`  to run my Welcome message eg:

```
#in main
p = multiprocess.Process(target = WelcomeMessage)
p.Start()
#doesn't get past this line
while digit == None:
    digit = kp.getKey() 
p.terminate()
```

But it would never register key input because it never got to the while loop. 
I've also tried using  `fork()`  in the os lib, (Since it's very similar to how it is in c); however, using `kill()` with  `SIGTERM`  to end the child process (Since the while condition is always true I didn't have a clean way to end it), but that ends up killing my parent as well.

This seemed like a simple problem, so I'm assuming it's because of my own lack of knowledge. If anyone can tell me the correct way to use fork or multiprocess to accomplish this, or has a good workaround for ending a while loop from the outside, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I have a way to end a while loop from the outside, but I think it depends on a particular process/threading setup. In essence, the `WelcomeMessage` function is in a class and the while loop is (say) `while self.x:`. You can have another function `Stop():` that has in its body `self.x = False`. That will stop the while loop. You also need to have at least two threads, one of which handles `kp.getKey()` and calls `theClass.Stop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but if I'm reading this correctly, it will have to wait until the while checks its condition again to end, correct? Since my message has a lot of sleeps (So the user has time to read it) I was hoping to do something like a break. 
Then again, I could set up a conditional after each sleep to check for <code>self.x</code>'s value...
Is there a library you usually use for multithreading like this?

Comment: I only came up with that particular solution recently, but that said, I don't know of a library for this. You could look at the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html); I think that's what you really want. Put `WelcomeMessage` in `theClass`, make `theClass` inherit from `Thread` (like so: `class theClass(Thread)`), make `theClass.__init__` call `WelcomeMessage`, and have another function in `theClass` (`Stop`) that sets `x` to `False` and call that from the main thread. That *might* work, I haven't tested it. (By the way, use backticks ` to enclose code fragments.)

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion, I hadn't thought of doing anything like that. Also thanks for explaining how to make the class inherit another one, python syntax is a little different from what I'm used to. (I spent the first hour trying to figure out why it was complaining about tabs)